# Extract some values on strings using PHP

Tags: php, string, extract

I need to extract values from strings where we have all informations split by "|" or "||" characters. These are two examples:

```
word1 | "word2[word3]" || number1 | word4
word5 | "word6[word7]" || number2 | word8
```

This is string syntax and I need to extract values inside 2 brackets (word3 and word7) and values after || (number1 and number2). How to do that?

Comment: you start with regexp.

Comment: You could as well use explode: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Combine explode and str_replace or preg_replace. Use replace to convert ||, [, and ] to | and then just explode on |. (I'd use preg_split though)

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment, I would use preg_split, as in:

```
$words = preg_split('/[\s\|"\[\]]+/', $string);
```

For

```
$string = 'word1 | "word2[word3]" || number1 | word4
           word5 | "word6[word7]" || number2 | word8';
```

the $words array will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => word1
    [1] => word2
    [2] => word3
    [3] => number1
    [4] => word4
    [5] => word5
    [6] => word6
    [7] => word7
    [8] => number2
    [9] => word8
)
```